# What does this Java code represent?

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

The following is a text rebus in the form of a Java program:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class WhatIsThis {
    private static Panel panel = new Panel();

    static {
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (panel.getComponentCount()>0) {
            panel.getComponentCount();
            panel.getClass();

            panel.getComponentCount();

            Container c = (Container)panel.getComponent(0); panel.remove(c);

            method1(c);

            panel.getComponentCount();
            panel.getClass();
        }

        /*
        // OPTIONAL:

        panel.getComponentCount();
        panel.getClass();

        panel.getComponentCount();

        init();

        panel.getComponentCount();
        panel.getClass();

        main(args);
        */
    }

    private static void init() {
        for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
            Container c = new Container();
            c.setName("ISB");
            panel.add(c);
        }
    }

    private static void method1(Container c) {
        method2(c);
    }

    private static void method2(Container c) {
        method3(c);
    }

    private static void method3(Container c) {
    }
}
```

What does it represent?  Bonus points if you can figure out what "ISB" means.

Comment: ewww...JAVA! Where is the Python and C(++) ;P

Comment: Awesome puzzle. I got a kick out of it once I figured it out.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard that optional intro before.

Comment: @IanMacDonald See BitCoder's [answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16415/4450).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is a representation of

> "99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall". You add 99 components to a panel, then proceed in a loop to get the count in the panel and then the count again (like in the song), and then remove one and pass it around (into a few methods, lol).

Had to honestly google "ISB", turns out it's

> "industry standard bottle", for a bottle of beer. :)

Comment: I think this seems correct

Comment: was thinking same . You should add lyrics :) http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/lyrics.html

Comment: 99 components inside a panel, 99 components inside! method1(panel.remove(panel.getComponent(0))); 98 components inside the panel!..

Comment: @MarkN Your code actually won't work because panel.remove(...) doesn't return anything.

Comment: @pacoverflow I know...you would have to override it with a new function (but it's the thought that *counts*) :(

Comment: It should also be noted that the puzzle used Containers. A beer bottle is a type of container, and of course "ISB" was used to indicate that.

Answer (score 3):

The optional section, as shyos said, states there are 0 bottles on the wall, puts 99 bottles of beer back on the wall, and then sings the song again:

```
panel.getComponentCount(); = No more bottles of beer
panel.getClass(); = on the wall

panel.getComponentCount(); = No more bottles of beer

init(); = Go to the store and buy some more

panel.getComponentCount(); = 99 bottles of beer
panel.getClass(); = on the wall

main(args); = repeat song and eventually crash (due to stack overflow), which is pretty much what a person would do if they had to sing the song over and over and over...
```

---

Note from OP: The lyrics for the optional section can be found in the book *[99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall: The Complete Lyrics](https://books.google.com/books?id=spmJzMQj8q4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Tim Nyberg (2006).

Comment: well actually optinal part is in the main. so once song(while) ends, optinal part states there is 0 bottle on the wall and then puts 99 bottles back to wall and sings the song again.

Comment: You got the "on the wall" parts right, though.  I wanted to differentiate between the "N bottles of beer on the wall" and "N bottles of beer" lines.  I'm going to fix up the rest of your answer.

Comment: "No more bottles of beer class javax.swing.JPanel! No more bottles of beer! Go to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer class javax.swing.JPanel!"